# Docker remove not existing container from `host` network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I cannot start one of my containers because there is an old version of the container stuck in the network.

When i try to start the container (with docker-compose) `docker-compose up -d service_name` i get the following error:

```
Creating project_service_name_1 ... error

ERROR: for project_service_name_1  Cannot start service service_name: endpoint with name project_service_name_1 already exists in network host

ERROR: for service_name  Cannot start service service_name: endpoint with name project_service_name_1 already exists in network host
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When i inspect the `host` network i get the info that there is a container connected to the network `docker network inspect host`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "host",
        "Id": "...",
        "Created": "2020-10-19T10:59:34.995303624+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "host",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": []
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "38d0a72cdb7d454082e2d41f092b5087e7f22cd192eea48ba70afffb5e7ca476": {
                "Name": "project_service_name_1",
                "EndpointID": "26d6e12b6983b57527cae6445d30ba35bf7aa9038b7b7877842c4d2ee961079e",
                "MacAddress": "",
                "IPv4Address": "",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            ...
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

`docker network disconnect host project_service_name_1` returns 0 (success) the first time but does not remove project_service_name_1 from the host network. the second time i get:

```
Error response from daemon: container 4bf82e4d1dfcf469e996aa412bfbd9bb52a2729dcd5cdc1dfa49d01ee25a213a is not connected to the network host
```

so i guess it removed `4bf82e4d1dfcf469e996aa412bfbd9bb52a2729dcd5cdc1dfa49d01ee25a213a` instead of `38d0a72cdb7d454082e2d41f092b5087e7f22cd192eea48ba70afffb5e7ca476` from the network (although `4bf82e4d1dfcf469e996aa412bfbd9bb52a2729dcd5cdc1dfa49d01ee25a213a` was not showing up in host network before)

disconnecting the old id of the container does not work as it's no longer existing `docker network disconnect host 38d0a72cdb7d454082e2d41f092b5087e7f22cd192eea48ba70afffb5e7ca476`:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: 38d0a72cdb7d454082e2d41f092b5087e7f22cd192eea48ba70afffb5e7ca476
```

I also cannot recreate the `host` network as it's pre-defined `docker network rm host`:

```
Error response from daemon: host is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
```

How do i get rid of the reminiscence of the container in the network?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @user969712 in the end, as far as i remember, i rebooted the server and that got rid of the no longer existing container. it's not really a good solution, but it seems it's the only one.

Comment: we had this situation again on another server for a while. so i can confirm i currently can only solve it be rebooting the server.